# How to upgrade to centos 8 from centos 7

Tags: centos

I have removed the yum package manager and using dnf only on centos 7
when i do `dnf upgrade` it does not work because i believe the values of `$releasever` in `/etc/yum.repos.d` is still gets the value as 7 and hence the url is pointed to the centos 7 url.

Now I belive `$releasever` value is taken from rpmdb.

How to perform this upgrade to centos 8 with the old variable values being updated to the new values for centos 8 in `/etc/yum.repos.d`
dnf has an option `--releasever RELEASEVER` to override the release server but not sure if it will update the rpmdb so that i can proceed with updates in future in a normal manner like `dnf update`

Comment: See this answer [How do I update a system from CentOS 7 to CentOS 8](https://serverfault.com/q/985478/267016) over on ServerFault, which suggests that this isn't a supported upgrade path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-place upgrades from RHEL 7.6 to RHEL 8.1 [are supported using Leapp](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/upgrading_to_rhel_8/index), with a number of limitations, but [there’s no supported equivalent to upgrade from CentOS 7 to CentOS 8](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=16116).

(And no, you can’t switch from CentOS to RHEL in-place either, to perform the upgrade that way.)